# How to binding data to custom transport controls?

Tags: uwp

I created a media transport controls.I want to binding a List to CustomMediaTransportControls.But I don't konw how to do this.

```
public List<PlayInfo> playInfo { get; set; }
public class PlayInfo
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public List<UrlList> urlList { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

I just need "name" what is about video quality,like HD.Change the quality of the playback video by selecting the sharpness.

```
<AppBarButton x:Name='PlayInfoButton'Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'>
               <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <Flyout>
                        <ListBox x:Name="PlayInfoListBox" >                        
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                 <DataTemplate >
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                                  </DataTemplate>

                             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                           </ListBox>
                     </Flyout>
              </AppBarButton.Flyout></AppBarButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <MediaPlayerElement Name="MainMediaPalyer"
                                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                                AutoPlay="True"
                                DoubleTapped="MainMediaPalyer_DoubleTapped">
                <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                    <control:CustomMediaTransportControls x:Name="mediaTransportControl"
                                                          Style="{StaticResource MyMediaTransportControls}"
                                                          IsCompact="True"
                                                          IsCompactOverlayEnabled="True"
                                                          IsZoomButtonVisible="false"
                                                          IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible="True"
                                                          IsVolumeButtonVisible="True"
                                                          IsStopButtonVisible="False" 
                                                          />
                </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
            </MediaPlayerElement>
```